# Ransack on enum filter for dropdown list

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

```
class Schedule < ApplicationRecord 
  belongs_to :event
  enum county: {USA: 0, INDIA: 1, Brasil: 2}
end
```

ransack select in index.erb.html

```
<%= f.collection_select :schedules_county_matches_all, Schedule.counties.map{ |dp| [dp.first, dp.first.humanize] }, :first.to_s, :second ,:include_blank => "All"%>
```

which gives output select dropdown list but not value as in Postgres database the value stored as integer not string

```
<li class=""><span>All</span></li>
<li class=""><span>USA</span></li>
.......
```

As working filter, I guess in view it should be added value in li

```
<li value=""><span>All</span></li>
<li value="0"><span>USA</span></li>
.......
```

Comment: What's the value it takes in order to save it as the `county` value?, you should be passing the country value, which is an integer, and using just the key to display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below line code for your problem

```
<%= f.select :schedules_county_matches_all, Schedule.counties.map { |r| [r[0], r[1].to_i] }, include_blank: true %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your ransacker.

```
  # user.rb
  enum role: [:Admin, :Analyst]
  ransacker :role, formatter: proc {|v| roles[v]} do |parent|
    parent.table[:role]
  end
```

And then add the field in your index.html.erb

```
<%= f.select :role_eq, User.roles.keys , {:include_blank => 'All Roles'}, { :class => 'form-control' } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= f.select :schedules_county_eq, options_for_select(Schedule.counties), include_blank: 'All' %>
```

Rails 7, Ransack 2.5.0. Lowercase strings.